# Does HTTP use cleartext?

Tags: http, https, cleartext

I've been reading about the differences between HTTP and HTTPS, and have also come across the term 'cleartext'. Does HTTP always use cleartext since it doesn't use encryption?

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be yes since HTTP does not encrypt data. cleartext = "immediately understandable to a human being without additional processing" so being able to read the data without needing to decrypt would fit these criteria.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. It transfers clear data without any additional processing.

As long as the data is text, you will get clear text. HTML pages, text files, json files all come as readable text.

But HTTP is also used to transport i.e. file downloads and images and obviously those are not transported as text but as binary data.

All data basically is not encrypted. This is what the S in HTTPS is responsible for.